# Reactjs state while value setted throw undefined error

Tags: reactjs

in **handleSelectChange** the ***console.log(this.state.selectValue);*** print's the value but when **addProduct** executed throw error that ***this.state.selectValue*** is undefined

> Cannot read property 'selectValue' of undefined

```
  handleSelectChange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({selectValue: e.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.selectValue); //here ok
  }

  addProduct(e){
    console.log(this.state.selectValue); //here error
    this.setState({products: [ ...this.state.products, this.state.selectValue]});

  }

<FormGroup>
     <Input type="select" value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleSelectChange.bind(this)} name="select" id="exampleSelect">
        <option value="Product 1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="Product 2">Product 2</option>
        <option value="Product 3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="Product 4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="Product 5">Product 5</option>
      </Input>
      <Input placeholder="Quantity" type="number" name="posotita" id="posotita" />
      <Button color="primary" onClick={this.addProduct}>Add</Button>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: show where you call addProduct

Comment: Has been asked 1 million times. Bind you context properly.

Comment: addProduct call need .bind(this), its ok now

Comment: is this solved or not?

Comment: @Omar its solved, I knew about binding but my brain had stuck, spend over an hour trying to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.state.selectValue` is undefined probably means that **this** now points to something else than a component where your state is. Try to bind this method like:

```
<Button color="primary" onClick={this.addProduct.bind(this)}>Add</Button>
```